# Localization not working for Portuguese (Brazil) in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios8

I have added localizable.string (Portuguese (Brazil)) for localization. Its working for iOS 9 version. But, its not effecting for iOS 8 itself. Its always showing English. I have seen some forums, they suggested change "Portuguese (Brazil))" to "pt-BR". But, for localized string file, I can't able to edit by double click. How to fix this, any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this finally. I hope it would help in future to someone who got same issue.

```
NSString *preferredLanguage = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"%@", preferredLanguage);

      if(IS_OS_9_BEFORE) {
 if ([preferredLanguage isEqualToString:@"pt"]) { 

            [[BundleLocalization sharedInstance] setLanguage:@"pt-BR"];
        }
      }
```

and don't forget to import following classes from git.

https://github.com/cmaftuleac/BundleLocalization